# What exactly does the last_value() window function do?

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

While testing my answer to [SQL - Getting data from first and last row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25870091/50552) I noticed something strange.  The `first_value` and `last_value` window functions appear to behave differently.

As expected, `first_value(col1) over (order by col2)` finds the value of `col1` from the row with the minimum value for `col2`.  But `last_value(col1) over (order by col2)` seems to find the value for the current row.  `last_value` seems unrelated to the group or partition it's operating on.

For the query below:

```
id  Session ID  bal
0   00000002    100
1   00000002    120
2   00000002    140
3   00000001    900
4   00000001    800
5   00000001    500
```

The expression:

```
last_value(bal) over (partition by [Session ID] order by id) as lv
```

Returns something different than:

```
first_value(bal) over (partition by [Session ID] order by id DESC) as fv_desc
```

Here's the result (note that the value of `lv` changes within one group):

```
lv       fv_desc
500      500
800      500
900      500
140      140
120      140
100      140
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle with some extra columns.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c244/13/0)  Reversing the `order by` or omitting `partition by` doesn't seem to impact what `last_value()` returns.

If I read the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx) correctly, it suggests that `last_value()` should work as the opposite of `first_value()`, which is different from what I observe during testing.

Does `last_value()` do what it is supposed to do?  Why does `last_value()` allow you to specify a `partition` and/or `order by` clause when it doesn't seem to use either?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because default window frame is `range between unbounded preceding and current row`, so the `last_value()` never looks beyond current row unless you change the frame.

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

> If ORDER BY is not specified entire partition is used for a window
>   frame. This applies only to functions that do not require ORDER BY
>   clause. If ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified,
>   RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for
>   window frame. This applies only to functions that have can accept
>   optional ROWS/RANGE specification. For example, ranking functions
>   cannot accept ROWS/RANGE, therefore this window frame is not applied
>   even though ORDER BY is present and ROWS/RANGE is not.

Since `last_value()` has an optional `order by` clause, its default window frame ends at the current row.  So with the default frame, no matter which partition or ordering you choose, `last_value()` returns the value from the current row.

Comment: ok, but "Why does last_value() allow you to specify a partition and/or order by clause when it doesn't seem to use either?"

Comment: I think it will use them if you just change the frame to include "unbounded following", but can't test this now.

Comment: @Leo: If the range ends at "current row", the `last_value()` must by definition be the current row.  So that does explain why neither sort order nor partition matters with the default range.